# подключение в bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap4

Не могу понять что делаю не так. Решил попробовать bootstrap 4. Вроде скачал настроил чтоб компилировался а вот стандартные примеры не работают(
Что то пропускаю не могу увидеть что...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Необходимые Мета-теги всегда на первом месте -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="2hfp1SzUoho7/TsGGGDaFdsuuDL0LX2hnUp6VkX3CUQ2K4K+xjboZdsXyp4oUHZj" crossorigin="anonymous">-->


    <link href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" >
    <script src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<!--меню-->
    <nav class="nav nav-inline">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </nav>



</div>

<!--подсказки-->
<div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">
        Tooltip on top
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">
        Tooltip on right
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom">
        Tooltip on bottom
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">
        Tooltip on left
    </button>
</div>
<!-- jQuery первый, затем Tether, затем Bootstrap JS. -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-THPy051/pYDQGanwU6poAc/hOdQxjnOEXzbT+OuUAFqNqFjL+4IGLBgCJC3ZOShY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.2.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-Plbmg8JY28KFelvJVai01l8WyZzrYWG825m+cZ0eDDS1f7d/js6ikvy1+X+guPIB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="VjEeINv9OSwtWFLAtmc4JCtEJXXBub00gtSnszmspDLCtC0I4z4nqz7rEFbIZLLU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

в меню Disabled работает только если подключить maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com

tooltip вообще не работает

с progress та же беда, однозначно что то не подключил, если кто тыкнет носом был бы благодарен

Comment: Для tooltip нужен popper js

Comment: добавил  с документации, тоже не помогло(

Comment: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
`

Comment: [документация](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/#js). смотрим чего не хватает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Недоподключена библиотека popper.js, неактивированы popover

> Many of our components require the use of JavaScript to function.
>   Specifically, they require jQuery, Popper.js, and our own JavaScript
>   plugins.
>   http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/#js
>
> Show components requiring JavaScript
>
> - Alerts for dismissing
> - Buttons for toggling states and checkbox/radio functionality
> - Carousel for all slide behaviors, controls, and indicators
> - Collapse for toggling visibility of content
> - Dropdowns for displaying and positioning (also requires Popper.js)
> - Modals for displaying, positioning, and scroll behavior
> - Navbar for extending our Collapse plugin to implement responsive behavior
> - Tooltips and popovers for displaying and positioning (also requires Popper.js)
> - Scrollspy for scroll behavior and navigation updates

[Активация](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/#example-enable-popovers-everywhere) popover. Например через аттрибут `data-toggle`:

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Необходимые Мета-теги всегда на первом месте -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <!--меню-->
    <nav class="nav nav-inline">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </nav>



  </div>

  <!--подсказки-->
  <div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on top
</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on right
</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus
sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on bottom
</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on left
</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо помогло! только disabled все равно не работает, но в целом понял чего не хватало, еще раз всем спасибо за помощь